# Getting the position of an element in a 2D array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Im trying to work out how to find the position of an element in a 2D array.

```
public static void checkTemps(double[][] arrayOfTemps)
    {
        for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<3;b++)
            {
                if((arrayOfTemps[a][b]<395) || (arrayOfTemps[a][b] >405))
                {
                    System.out.println(arrayOfTemps[a][b]+" is faulty");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

That is what I have so far. I need to work out which position in the array is faulty, if it is below 395 or above 405. I know that this will return a number then ' is faulty' but its what I have so far.

Comment: Do you want o store the 'row' and 'col' positions where his condition happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `a` and `b` to the `System.out.println()` statement:

```
System.out.println("Element[" + a + "][" + b + "] is faulty");
```

Comment: thanks!, dont know why I didnt think of that. Mind blank

Comment: was not me lol, ive not got enough rep to upvote yet :( thanks again for the answer though!